# take some pictures or take few pictures

Tags: word-choice, quantifiers

hello  english community

I am a new English learner and new user of stack exchange too. I am confused in the following  sentence :-

Jane wanted a camera to take _________ pictures of her friends on Graduation Day, but now she doesn't need it.
which is correct

- a) take some picture
- b) take few picture

Comment: (1) _Pictures_ in the example is plural; you refer to it as singular _picture_ in your choices, so both are wrong. (2) Either _some_ or _a few_ is OK, no difference, but **not** _few_, which has a different meaning from _a few_, with indefinite article.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and I would not interpret them differently: they both  mean the same thing.

Jane wanted a camera to take some pictures of her friends on Graduation Day, but now she doesn't need it.

or

Jane wanted a camera to take a few pictures of her friends on Graduation Day, but now she doesn't need it.

**Note:** in the second version you need the indefinite article *a* in front of the word *few*.